# Webdriver issue - getting web element on Firefox browser using python is not possible

Tags: python, selenium

I am facing issue with Python web driver. I am able to launch the browser through webdriver and open required URL and login, but issue comes later when I try to find object of any element present on screen, it waits for long time(some times 30 min to 1 hr) to get web element. I have tried creating profile as given below, but still result is same.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("webdriver.load.strategy", unicode("unstable")).  
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

Do any 1 know solution for this?
Note: It works fine on Chrome.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Can you please show the traceback of the error?

Comment: Please add a sample HTML with a WebElement and the code where you try to find it. (It is helpful to show the error message)

Comment: 3 upvotes, I dont understand the relation between upvotes and good question